# OpenSSL connection fails with non-blocking socket

Tags: c++, sockets, ssl, openssl, nonblocking

I have an OpenSSL server that has echo functionality as described [here](https://www.cs.utah.edu/~swalton/listings/articles/ssl_server.c) and a client as described [here](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/SSL/TLS_Client). I made some minor changes to the server (e.g. changing the certifiacte and private key paths, adding some more debug outputs,...) and in the client I just removed the "BIO* out" and printed the BIO_read result to the console instead.
Also both client and server use TLSv1_1_client_method and TLSv1_1_server_method respectively.

The codes work fine together, but if I add "BIO_set_nbio(web, 1);" to the client just before BIO_do_connect, the connection doesn't work anymore. BIO_do_connect returns -1. Can this be a handshake problem and if so, how can I handshake properly with non-blocking sockets?

This error first occurred in a larger project of mine. I just used the example codes to verify it. My problem is, I need non-blocking sockets, because I am calling BIO_read from a different thread and I can't join the thread if it's stuck trying to read.

I also tried to set the socket to non-blocking by using fd_set and select, but that throws the WSAENOTSOCK error (10038). I did the following:

Header:

```
BIO* _bio;
SSL* _ssl;
FD_SET _fdSet;
SOCKET _socket;
timeval t;
```

on connecting:

```
_bio = BIO_new_ssl_connect(_ctx);
BIO_get_ssl(_bio, &_ssl);
SSL_set_mode(_ssl, SSL_MODE_AUTO_RETRY);
BIO_set_conn_hostname(_bio, _address); // _address is "hostname:port"
int connectResult = BIO_do_connect(_bio);

// ... error handling for connect, certificate verification

BIO_get_fd(_bio, _socket);
FD_ZERO(&_fdSet);
FD_SET(_socket, &_fdSet);
t.tv_sec = 2;
t.tv_usec = 0;
```

In the thread that polls the socket:

```
int selectResult = select(0, &fdSet, NULL, NULL, &t); // <-- throws WSAENOTSOCK
if (selectResult > 0)
    x = BIO_read(_bio, &buf, 1);
```

Is select even doable if you have a BIO socket?

The client is on Windows 7 64 Bit, the server runs on Ubuntu 64 bit on a VM on the same host as my Windows 7.

Comment: If the polling is done from another thread, how do you make sure that there is actually a valid socket before it enters the select?

Comment: I am creating the socket in a function I call "connect" and only after it connected and verified the certificate successfully, this function starts the threads (for sending and receiving). I hope OpenSSL doesn't have a problem with me threading class member functions by using std::thread?

Comment: Don't think it does, I've done the same thing with boost threads. But I do believe that the FD_SET has to be recreated for each select. Also the timeout has to be reset as well, as select actually modifies that parameters value.

Comment: Unfortunately I still get error 10038 (WSAENOTSOCK) if I move those last 5 commands from my "on connecting" block right above the select. How did you do it?

Comment: I don't use BIO-hell :p I used libssh2 instead. I did look at BIO stuff - but everything seemed to complex. So maybe I should augment my previous statement, I've done almost the same thing - only using a different library :| my bad.

Comment: Ok, it's good to know that you view BIO as hell, because virtually all example OpenSSL clients use BIO (and thus I thought it was a good thing), while on the other hand I didn't find a single OpenSSL server that uses BIO, so I am kinda debugging two different socket implementations when I really shouldn't be. Did you program a server, too, and if you did, what lib did you use?

Comment: No, no server. All help I could find online for that said, don't do it. And it really wasn't needed. I just needed the program to access a remote server, and for that I used libssh2.