# Non-blocking BIO and hang after BIO_do_connect

Tags: c, ssl, network-programming, openssl

I am writing a small little IRC bot in C using openssl to start a secure socket. It isn't the most beautifully written bot, but its mostly just to see how the openssl API works. Currently I have the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <openssl/bio.h>
#include <openssl/ssl.h>
#include <openssl/err.h>

int main() {
    SSL_load_error_strings();
    ERR_load_BIO_strings();
    OpenSSL_add_all_algorithms();

    BIO *bio;
    SSL_CTX * ctx = SSL_CTX_new(SSLv23_client_method());
    SSL * ssl;

    SSL_CTX_load_verify_locations(ctx, NULL, "/etc/ssl/certs/");
    bio = BIO_new_ssl_connect(ctx);
    BIO_get_ssl(bio, & ssl);
    SSL_set_mode(ssl, SSL_MODE_AUTO_RETRY);
    BIO_set_nbio(bio, 1);
    BIO_set_conn_hostname(bio, "irc.freenode.net:6697");
    BIO_do_connect(bio);

    if(SSL_get_verify_result(ssl) != X509_V_OK) {
        printf("error\n");
    }

    char irc1[] = "NICK bartender\r\n";
    char irc2[] = "USER bartender * * :serve(&drinks);\r\n";

    BIO_write(bio, irc1, strlen(irc1));
    BIO_write(bio, irc2, strlen(irc2));

    fd_set read_set;
    int sock = BIO_get_fd(bio, NULL);

    while(1) {
        FD_ZERO(&read_set);
        FD_SET(sock, &read_set);

        struct timeval timeout = { 0, 0 };
        select(sock+1, &read_set, NULL, NULL, &timeout);

        if(FD_ISSET(sock, &read_set)) {
            char buf[21];
            size_t x = BIO_read(bio, buf, 20);

            if(x == 0) {
                continue;
            } else if(x == -1){
                int code = ERR_get_error();

                if(code == 0) {
                    continue;
                }

                printf("(%d)%s\n", code, ERR_error_string(code, NULL));
            } else {
                buf[x] = '\0';
                printf("%s", buf);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Whenever I compile and run this code, it just hangs and prints nothing. However, if I remove line 20 (which currently puts the socket into nonblocking mode) it works fine. Why does putting the socket in non-blocking mode cause this behavior? Thank you and have a great day!

Comment: You can't just change any socket to Jon-blocking mode and expect the same code to keep working. There is more work to do, and I n the case of SSL sockets a great deal more. See the OpenSSL documentation. Too broad.

Comment: I fail to see how "putting a BIO object in nonblocking mode" is too broad. I am sure there is more that needs to be done, otherwise it would be working. What needs to be done? I have already read the openssl man pages, and consulted google and previous SO answers. I can't find anything else I need to do.

Comment: There is a lot more hat needs to be done, and it is all documented in *man select* and the OpenSSL documentation, and it is too broad to answer here.

Comment: Its not though. I've done everything necessary for select. And it clearly isn't too broad if there was short answer given.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Whenever I run this code, it just hangs and prints nothing. However, if I remove line 20 (which currently puts the socket into nonblocking mode) it works fine.

`BIO_do_connect` returns immediately in non-blocking mode. You should loop on `BIO_should_retry`. Here's what the man page has to say about [`BIO_do_connect`](http://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/crypto/BIO_s_connect.html):

> BIO_do_connect() attempts to connect the supplied BIO. It returns 1 if
>   the connection was established successfully. A zero or negative value
>   is returned if the connection could not be established, the call
>   BIO_should_retry() should be used for non blocking connect BIOs to
>   determine if the call should be retried.

---

> Why does putting the socket in non-blocking mode cause this behavior?

The call to `BIO_do_connect` returns immediately; the socket/bio is probably not ready for data (yet).

---

An alternative to looping on `BIO_do_connect`/`BIO_should_retry` is to wait on the underlying file descriptor. Its the technique used by OpenSSL in the `ocsp` subcommand (the source can be found in `<openssl src>/apps/ocsp.c`):

```
if (req_timeout != -1)
    BIO_set_nbio(cbio, 1);

rv = BIO_do_connect(cbio);

if ((rv <= 0) && ((req_timeout == -1) || !BIO_should_retry(cbio))) {
    BIO_puts(err, "Error connecting BIO\n");
    return NULL;
}

if (BIO_get_fd(cbio, &fd) < 0) {
    BIO_puts(bio_err, "Can't get connection fd\n");
    goto err;
}

if (req_timeout != -1 && rv <= 0) {
    FD_ZERO(&confds);
    openssl_fdset(fd, &confds);
    tv.tv_usec = 0;
    tv.tv_sec = req_timeout;
    rv = select(fd + 1, NULL, (void *)&confds, NULL, &tv);
    if (rv == 0) {
        BIO_puts(err, "Timeout on connect\n");
        return NULL;
    }
}
```

---

Also see [Non-blocking BIO and BIO_do_connect problem](http://openssl.6102.n7.nabble.com/Non-blocking-BIO-and-BIO-do-connect-problem-td6934.html) on the OpenSSL Users mailing list. There's also a [few hits on Stack Overflow](http://www.google.com/search?q=Non-blocking+BIO+and+BIO_do_connect+site%3Astackoverflow.com), but I'm not sure which is the best fit for this question:

- [nonblocking BIO_do_connect blocked when there is no internet connected](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38886648)
- [OpenSSL connection fails with non-blocking socket](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29388113)
- [Changing an OpenSSL BIO from blocking to non-blocking mode](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8411168)
- [Unable to establish connection using OpenSSL BIO interface](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15972336)

Comment: Your code doesn't agree with your quotation. You need to loop while `BIO_should_retry()` is true. Looping while `BIO_do_cnnect()` is failing is certaimly incorrect.

Comment: @EJP - *"Looping while BIO_do_cnnect() is failing is certaimly incorrect...."* - you should familiarize yourself with OpenSSL practices. See, for example, [Non-blocking BIO and BIO_do_connect problem](http://openssl.6102.n7.nabble.com/Non-blocking-BIO-and-BIO-do-connect-problem-td6934.html) on the OpenSSL mailing list. Dr. Henson is one of the maintainers, so pay particular attention to what he has to say.